# useNavigate doesn’t work on React test mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock the implementation of useNavigate with jest to test a component using react testing library, but when i run my test jest don’t recognize the mocked function.

here is the component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import Somelogo from "../../assets/some-logo.svg";

export default function NavBar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <AppBar color="primary" position="sticky">
      <Toolbar>
        <img
          width="100%"
          style={{ maxWidth: "50px" }}
          height="auto"
          src={Somelogo}
          alt="some logo"
        />
        <Typography
          variant="h6"
          component="div"
          sx={{ flexGrow: 1, textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          E-core Breakdown
        </Typography>
        <Button color="info" onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
          Home
        </Button>
        <Button color="info" onClick={() => navigate("/accounts")}>
          Accounts
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

here is my test

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "../../utils/test.utils";
import Navbar from "../navbar";

const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-router", () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual("react-router") as any),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));

describe("<Navbar />", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedUsedNavigate.mockReset();
  });

  test("should navigate to the correct page", () => {
    render(<Navbar />);

    const accountButton = screen.getByText("Accounts", { exact: false });

    userEvent.click(accountButton);

    expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

When i run this test it returns to me that the test failed. I read some documentations and saw examples using the exact same mock but to me it doesn’t work.

[failed test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq7Mp.png)

Comment: Does it navigate properly when not using jest?

Comment: yes, running the app everything works just fine, is just on the test that the mocked version doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I find what i was doing wrong, i needed to wait for the expected result to happen, adding a waitfor to the test.

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { render, screen } from "../../utils/test.utils";
import Navbar from "../navbar";

const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock("react-router", () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual("react-router") as any),
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));

describe("<Navbar />", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedUsedNavigate.mockReset();
  });

  test("should navigate to the correct page", () => {
    render(<Navbar />);

    const accountButton = screen.getByText("Accounts", { exact: false });

    userEvent.click(accountButton);

    await waitFor(() => expect(mockedUsedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
  });
});
```